# Venezuela Hyperinflation in 2014 on an IS LM FX model

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, economic-crisis

In 2014 Venezuela began experiencing some of the worst hyperinflation. I wanted to know how this situation would be represented on a IS LM FX model, and the consequences of the hyperinflation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you represent hyperinflation in a model with fixed prices?

Comment: @GradaGukovic prices in IS LM are not fixed

Comment: @1muflon1 of course they are fixed. The IS curve represents the set of possible equilibria on the goods market and the LM - the set of the equilibria on the money market. Prices are present only in the LM equation and they are exogenous there. If the goods equilibrium changes ( for example G goes up) the interest rate adjusts, but prices stay the same.

Comment: @GradaGukovic no prices are not exogenous in IS-LM. Both IS-LM curves can shift the IS-LM does not assumes these curves are fixed. For example, if IS is fixed and there is monetary expansion that will shift LM curve to the right. LM would intersect IS at a new point. Next all points of intersection between IS-LM can be traced on new output-price diagram where they will for aggregate demand curve. You will see that all these intersections will give you downward sloping AD curve. So different points of intersection between IS-LM are associated with different price level. If you don’t believe

Comment: @GradaGukovic me have a look at Blanchard et al Macroeconomics pp 193

Comment: @1muflon1 of course I know how to derive the AD curve. But the prices in that diagram come from the LM equation, where they are exogenous.  The primary source of the action regarding inflation in the AS-AD Model is the AS-curve.

Comment: @1muflon1 Whenever you quote a textbook that has new edition every year you should tell, which edition you are using. FYI there is no AD or aggregate demand in the most recent one. It uses a "IS-LM-PC" model instead of AS-AD

Comment: @GradaGukovic It’s 2nd edition, in any case then we are the same page. But the price level is both determined by shifts in AS and AD. The price level in LM curve has to be always consistent with AD=AS